# Assetic not outputting more than one Javascript tag

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I'm learning Symfony 2 and am currently using Assetic to manage my CSS and Javascript files, like so:

```
{% stylesheets '@testMainBundle/Resources/public/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{% javascripts '@testMainBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

In `@testMainBundle/Resources/public/js` I have 3 files: `bootstrap.min.js`, `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` and `main.js`. However, the source code of the webpage comes out as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/app_dev.php/js/4a0d3cd_part_1_bootstrap.min_1.js"></script>
```

Clearly, Assetic is only serving one file from that directory, the bootstrap file. I've checked and it's not combining the files, it's *only* the `bootstrap.min.js` file that's being output.

Assetic is working fine with two CSS files, however. I've tried refreshing my browser cache however nothing changes.

Also, as a side question, how do I make sure that Assetic outputs `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` before `bootstrap.min.js`? Bootstrap relies on jQuery so can't be printed first.

Comment: In `dev` environment, Symfony2 serves each file individually to ease debugging.

Comment: I know, that wasn't the problem. Read the question again.

Comment: Maybe it's clear for you, but you don't speak about `dev` and `prod` environments in your question. You said _I've checked and it's not combining the files_ just after a code containing `/app_dev.php/js/`, this was just the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my own solution, I had to do the following:

```
{% javascripts
    '@testMainBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'
    '@testMainBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Not sure if Assetic is documented to work this way however it seems to print out the jQuery include first and then every other file now. Perfect!